# How could save an array values using Model

Tags: keystonejs

How can do add an array of values into keystone js Model? Like I need to save a list of name, address and phone number into Model.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the types `TextArray` and `NumberArray`. They are not yet in the official documentation, but there is a [new staging documentaton url](http://keystonejs.netlify.com/api/field/numberarray/)
 where you can find those fields.

Additional you can have a look at the GitHub issues about [creating the array fields](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/13) and about [creating the docs about them](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/1021).

**Update:**

If you need several values as a list, I would suggest to create a separate model out the values (name, age, phone, etc.) and then make a `Relationship` field with `many:true`. There is no other way for several fields in a list.

Comment: Thanks, @Moema. But as i mentioned in the question, i need a multidimensional array like name, age and phone.